# Drools 6.5 Executing Specific Rule Using a Custom Agenda Filter Not Working

Tags: drools, kie

I have a requirement to execute specific rules using their using associated values and tried implementing a custom Agenda Filter to only execute one particular rule at a time but it appears to execute all rules. I'm using a stateless session that i defined like this:

```
   @Bean
     @ConditionalOnMissingBean(KieSession.class)
     public StatelessKieSession kieSession() throws IOException {   
         return kieContainer().newStatelessKieSession();
     }
```

My logic for iterating the Map and executing each rule is as follows:

```
for (Map.Entry<Long, String> entry : ruleIdsAndData.entrySet()){

    List<Object> facts = new ArrayList<Object>();
    facts.add(entry.getValue());

    Map<String, String> ruleResponse = new HashMap<String, String>();
    kieSession.setGlobal("ruleResponse", ruleResponse);                     

    TrackingAgendaEventListener agendaEventListener = new TrackingAgendaEventListener();
    kieSession.addEventListener(agendaEventListener);

    String ruleName = myRuleService.retrieveRuleNameById(entry.getKey());               
    log.debug("Attempting to fire the following rule : " + ruleName);

    facts.add(new FireAllRulesCommand(new RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter(ruleName)));   
    kieSession.execute(facts);

    log.debug("RuleResponse after rule has fired is : " + ruleResponse);                                                            
}
```

and the `RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter` class looks like this:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.kie.api.runtime.rule.AgendaFilter;
import org.kie.api.runtime.rule.Match;

    @Slf4j
    public class RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter implements AgendaFilter {

        private final String ruleName;

        private final boolean accept;

        public RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter(final String name) {
            this(name, true);
        }

        public RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter(final String name, final boolean accept) {
            this.ruleName = name;
            this.accept = accept;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return ruleName;
        }

        public boolean isAccept() {
            return accept;
        }

        public boolean accept( Match match) {
            log.debug("Comparing : " + match.getRule().getName() + " to ruleName : " + this.ruleName);
            if (match.getRule().getName().equals(this.ruleName)) {
                return this.accept;
            } else {
                return !this.accept;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why this would execute a different rule to the one i specify in `ruleName`?

Comment: What makes you say that all rules are executed with each call to execute?

Comment: if i hardcode my ruleName into the the following line, the console output displays another ruleName : facts.add(new FireAllRulesCommand(new RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter("myHardCodedRuleName")));  I'm wondering if the above config is OK or should i be passing a List of Commands & use CommandFactory.newBatchExecution....

Comment: Who is creating those logs? What is `TrackingAgendaEventListener` doing?

Comment: Please edit this, the console output and *how the console output is produced* into your question. - The log line "Comparing : ... " should be visible for all matching rules.

Comment: My application is generating the console output locally and the TrackingAgendaEventListener is currently not in use.  I can't see any logging for the line "Comparing....." that i added to the RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter

Comment: If you can't explain how you verify that all rules are executed I can't help you. If the log.debug call in the accept method doesn't produce any output then you don't have the AgendaFilter active.

Comment: OK thanks, is there any reason why the AgendaFilter wouldn't activate?

Comment: Ah, good question. Made me re-read your code more thoroughly. It had the air of containing all ingredients, but one must add them judiciously ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are adding facts to a List:

```
List<Object> facts = new ArrayList<Object>();
facts.add(entry.getValue());
```

And here you add another Object, a FireAllRulesCommand:

```
facts.add(new FireAllRulesCommand(new RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter(ruleName)));
```

And then you call

```
kieSession.execute(facts);
```

which inserts all facts and then calls fireAllRules. So the AgendaFilter is just a fact in WM.

Use a statefull session, insert the facts and call fireAllRules with the AgendaFilter as an argument.

Comment: Great thanks, it's activating the Agenda Filter now when i used a statefulSession so i can see the correct logging.  If i have 2 rules and only 1 executes and the other doesn't when i'd expect the 2 to execute.  Changing the session to a statefulSession wouldn't cause only 1 rule to execute if your calling session.insert or session.fireAllRules(...) multiple times?

Comment: When i pass my second ruleName to the Agenda Filter it doesn't log, but the first does so my first rule gets executed but the second rule doesn't

Comment: Not sure I understand these comments. - Take care, you'll have to recreate and dispose a  stateful session before and after calling fireAllRules to get the same result as with a stateless session.

Comment: Hi laune, my requirement is fairly simple.  I need to iterate a Map or batch of rules and execute each rule individually with its associated value(s). After changing my stateless session to a stateful one, the Agenda filter ran once for my first rule but not on my second.  I could only see one log statement "Comparing....." for the first rule.  Is there any reason why i would see this behavior?

Comment: Also, I'm loading the rules into the session from a DB at startup so I can't recreate the session each time I want to execute a rule.

Comment: You can keep the KieBase, the result of compiling the rules. From this, you can create a session any number of times. - You'll have to post some code for reproducing the effect ("only see one log statemtent") so that folks can look into it. Your descriptions are too sketchy.